# Forms Module not found in Child module

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-module

I am trying to use `ReactiveFormsModule`. I imported it in `app.module`. My component is in child module, but child module not able to get that.

Should I want to import this module in each child modules? **Or** is there any way to keep it in appmodule and make it work in all child modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That's the way how encapsulation in Angular works.**

It prevents from invisible dependencies and makes it very clear what the module needs. How you could approach it, is by creating a `SharedModule`, which contains all necessary modules to import it into the respective module.

This is a very common behavior. For an example you can have a look here: [how to use parent module component in child module component in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471095/how-to-use-parent-module-component-in-child-module-component-in-angular2)